# IronPython 'type' object has no attribute 'NewMode'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ironpython

I have confusing error with my c# application with is extended with ironpython.

The following code-ling:

```
self.Mask.Control.Mode = WindowState.NewMode
```

throw this error:

> 'type' object has no attribute 'NewMode'

My Exception:

> Name: NewDocument
>
> Exception: 'type' object has no attribute 'NewMode'
>
> StackTrace:    bei
>   IronPython.Runtime.Binding.MetaPythonType.FastGetBinderHelper.ErrorBinder.Target(CodeContext
>   context, Object self, Object& result)    bei
>   IronPython.Runtime.Types.TypeGetBase.RunDelegatesNoOptimize(Object
>   self, CodeContext context)    bei
>   IronPython.Runtime.Types.SystemTypeGet.Target(CallSite site, Object
>   self, CodeContext context)    bei
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    bei
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    bei
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](T0
>   arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)    bei
>   IronPython.Runtime.FunctionCaller`2.Call2(CallSite site, CodeContext
>   context, Object func, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)    bei
>   IronPython.Runtime.Method.MethodBinding`1.SelfTarget(CallSite site,
>   CodeContext context, Object target, T0 arg0)    bei
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    bei
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    bei
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0
>   arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)    bei
>   IronPython.Runtime.FunctionCaller`3.Call3(CallSite site, CodeContext
>   context, Object func, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)    bei
>   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object )    bei
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)    bei CallSite.Target(Closure ,
>   CallSite , Object , Object , Object )    bei
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)    bei lambda_method(Closure ,
>   DynamicOperations , CallSiteBinder , Object , Object[] )    bei
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DynamicOperations.InvokeMember(Object obj,
>   String memberName, Boolean ignoreCase, Object[] parameters)    bei
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ObjectOperations.InvokeMember(Object obj,
>   String memberName, Object[] parameters)    bei
>   ESS.MS.Framework.Script.IronPythonScript.CallFunction(Object Class,
>   String Method, Object[] Arguments)

The problem is, that i can't reproduce the error, some times it occurs immediately
and some times it occurs after an hour of using my program.

Maybe some one has an idea.

(I am using .Net 4.0 and IronPython 2.7.4)

Thank you!

Comment: I maybe found solution, i use import my enum twice, so maybe that was the problem.